# What does "function (assert)" do?

Tags: qunit

I've just started becoming acquainted with qunit and I'm trying to get through the official introduction.
There are quite a lot of questions arising and I can't find anything on their documentation about qunit or elsewhere on the web.

What does "function (assert)" do? Assert is a category in qunit for several assertion methods, yet it isn't a method by itself. So if I put "assert" into the parameter of a function, what happens? Are all assertion methods associated with "assert" executed in the test?

https://qunitjs.com/intro/

Here's one piece of code where this syntax is used

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Refactored date examples</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.5.0.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="prettydate.js"></script>

  <script>
  QUnit.test("prettydate basics", function( assert ) {
    var now = "2008/01/28 22:25:00";
    assert.equal(prettyDate(now, "2008/01/28 22:24:30"), "just now");
    assert.equal(prettyDate(now, "2008/01/28 22:23:30"), "1 minute ago");
    assert.equal(prettyDate(now, "2008/01/28 21:23:30"), "1 hour ago");
    assert.equal(prettyDate(now, "2008/01/27 22:23:30"), "Yesterday");
    assert.equal(prettyDate(now, "2008/01/26 22:23:30"), "2 days ago");
    assert.equal(prettyDate(now, "2007/01/26 22:23:30"), undefined);
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="qunit"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full line is:

```
QUnit.test("prettydate basics", function( assert ) {
```

This calls the function `QUnit.test`, and you're passing it a callback. That callback takes one parameter. `QUnit.test` will pass an object as the first argument to your callback, which becomes your `assert` parameter. That object has various methods for asserting things.

It's basically injecting the assertion object into your code so you can use it to make assertions.

Roughly `QUnit.test` is implemented like this:

```
QUnit.test = function (name, callback) {
    const assert = {
        equal: function () { ... },
        ...
    };

    callback(assert);
};
```

Comment: To add just a bit, the point of doing this is so that you _don't_ have to use the global `QUnit` object inside your test, but rather the local `assert` object. Additionally, you now have to use the `assert` object to do asynchronous testing (whereas you used to be able to use the global `QUnit` object).